# Tailwind CSS: overflow-hidden does not hide a full translate

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm working with Tailwind CSS and I can't quite figure out how to remove the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the page. I thought that setting `overflow-hidden` would do the trick, but there is still a scroll due to the `translate-x-full` in the child component. Does anyone spot how I keep the overflow hidden while achieving the translation for the purposes of animation? I've been following [this tutorial](https://devdojo.com/tnylea/creating-a-slider-with-tailwind-css), so there could also be something about the styling used there that causes the scroll bars to appear. Thanks for your help!

[image: tailwind]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `100vh` is too big. Just use `100%` or `h-full` instead. This depends on the device you are on. This is a bug that will be addressed in the future. `100vh` just does not seem to be correct on all screens.

It is especially annoying if you develop for mobile devices. They could not make it standardized yet so on iOS and Android you might get different results - it is because of the OS and native menu bars. You can read about that online.

For the solution, I just focused on that scroll bar issue. The js-part seems to be buggy. I just added it that you can see the effect.

```js
function nextSlide() {
  let activeSlide = document.querySelector('.slide.translate-x-0');
  activeSlide.classList.remove('translate-x-0');
  activeSlide.classList.add('-translate-x-full');

  let nextSlide = activeSlide.nextElementSibling;
  nextSlide.classList.remove('translate-x-full');
  nextSlide.classList.add('translate-x-0');
}

function previousSlide() {
  let activeSlide = document.querySelector('.slide.translate-x-0');
  activeSlide.classList.remove('translate-x-0');
  activeSlide.classList.add('translate-x-full');

  let previousSlide = activeSlide.previousElementSibling;
  previousSlide.classList.remove('-translate-x-full');
  previousSlide.classList.add('translate-x-0');
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.7/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html class="h-full">

<body class="h-full">
  <div class="relative h-full">
    <div class="h-full absolute inset-0 w-screen bg-pink-500 text-white flex items-center justify-center text-5xl transition-all ease-in-out duration-1000 transform translate-x-0 slide">Hello</div>
    <div class="h-full absolute inset-0 w-screen bg-purple-500 text-white flex items-center justify-center text-5xl transition-all ease-in-out duration-1000 transform translate-x-full slide">There</div>
    <div class="h-full absolute inset-0 w-screen bg-teal-500 text-white flex items-center justify-center text-5xl transition-all ease-in-out duration-1000 transform translate-x-full slide">Booya!</div>
    <div onclick="nextSlide()" class="fixed bottom-0 right-0 bg-white w-16 h-16 flex items-center justify-center text-black cursor-pointer">&#x276F;</div>
    <div onclick="previousSlide()" class="fixed bottom-0 right-0 bg-white w-16 h-16 mr-16 border-r border-gray-400 flex items-center justify-center text-black cursor-pointer">&#x276E;</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Although when I click on `Run code snippet`, the same scrollbar issue is there.

Comment: @Mike It is there because it is a slider. You cannot get rid of the x-scrolling. Otherwise you have to adjust the markup and only display 1 slide or rather 1 div since it is no longer a slide then.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for this clarification! I understand now what's going on.